# Gitlab coverage parsing has negative percentage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have setup gitlab unit-test using Jest like below, In this project I only have one test that has reporter and coverage. There are another test that does not have reporter nor coverage

[image]

I used regex to parse the number of percentage for Lines: xx.xx%.
In the Merge Request, it renders the information like below

[image]

Based on the image above, my question are:

1. why there are 2 percentages 26.11% (-0.26%)
2. why the second percentage is negative
3. How to show only 1 percentage

Comment: (a). The first percentage (26.11%) is your _new_ code coverage;  (b). The second percentage (-0.26%) denotes the amount by which your code coverage has _decreased_.  It is negative to show decrement; (c) I don't really think you want to do that - since it is an indication that you need to add more tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a). The first percentage (26.11%) is your *new* code coverage;

(b). The second percentage (-0.26%) denotes the amount by which your code coverage has *decreased* (it is negative to show decrement);

(c). I don't really think you want to do that - it is an indication that you need to add more tests.